# Inconsistent operand constraints

Tags: c++, debian, vmware-tools

I have installed Raspberry Pi Desktop OS on my VMvare virtual machine. Trying to install open-vm-tools:

```
git clone https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools.git
autoreconf -i
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Got error while make:

```
backdoorGcc64.c: In function ‘Backdoor_InOut’:
backdoorGcc64.c:78:4: error: inconsistent operand constraints in an ‘asm’
    __asm__ __volatile__(
    ^~~~~~~
```

Why I'm getting this and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Looking at (what I believe is) the [code](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/blob/master/open-vm-tools/lib/backdoor/backdoorGcc64.c) here, I'm guessing some type of mismatch between building for 32 bit and 64 bit?  The "64" in backdoorGcc64.c says it's trying to build a 64bit file, but if it were somehow using a 32 bit compiler, you might get an error like that.

Comment: why don't you just install via the system package manager: `apt install open-vm-tools`